# Python webapp2: redirect back

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect, webapp2

I'm using the google app engine for a basic app.

The scenario is simple: i click Logout and I want my Logout handler to redirect me back to the page from where I came from.

How do I achieve this?
thnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When [creating logout url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions) you can pass in the url you want user to be redirected to, in your case his current url. Something like this (I'm not Python dev, so ...):

```
users.create_logout_url(self.request.url)
```

Comment: The full command is: `users.create_logout_url(self.request.url)`