# Redirect to previous url in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to make a logout handler to redirect to whatever url called it.

There's a similar question [Python webapp2: redirect back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889236/python-webapp2-redirect-back)

but if I called `self.request.url` in the `LogoutHandler` it returns the url used to map to this handler not the page that redirected to that url.

Here's how the structure goes

```
class LogoutHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     #delete user cookies
     url = self.request.url 
     # this prints (http://www.domain/logout) not (http://www.domain)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     #send "/logout" as the href in an anchor tag"for logout" in a template 

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
     .....
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/logout', LogoutHandler),
     .....
     .....
    ], debug = True)
```

How can I get 'http://www.domain' or whatever redirected to the logout without adding the previous url as a querystring in the logout url?

webapp2, python 2.7 , Google app engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could probably use the referrer header in this instance, though you'll want a reasonable default for browsers which do not provide it.
Also be wary of redirect loops..

[get the referer url in python/webapp2 for a post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273085/get-the-referer-url-in-python-webapp2-for-a-post-request)